# Как командой из первого скрипта открыть второй .py скрипт в новом окне консоли?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как командой из первого скрипта открыть второй .py скрипт в **новом** окне консоли?

Comment: Какая ОС?......

Comment: @andreymal win7

Comment: связанный вопрос [How can I open two consoles from a single script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19479504/4279)

Comment: связанный вопрос [keep multiple console windows open from batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12122535/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Show messages in two new console windows simultaneously."""
import sys
import platform
from subprocess import Popen

messages = 'This is Console1', 'This is Console2'

# define a command that starts new terminal
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    new_window_command = "cmd.exe /c start".split()
else:  #XXX this can be made more portable
    new_window_command = "x-terminal-emulator -e".split()

# open new consoles, display messages
echo = [sys.executable, "-c",
        "import sys; print(sys.argv[1]); input('Press Enter..')"]
processes = [Popen(new_window_command + echo + [msg])  for msg in messages]

# wait for the windows to be closed
for proc in processes:
    proc.wait()
```

Код взят с англоязычного stackoverflow.com [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479504/how-can-i-open-two-consoles-from-a-single-script)

Автор: [jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/jfs)

Comment: по обоим методам открывает в том же окне консоли, первый вариант как я понял в python 3 запускается так exec(open("...py").read())

Comment: что то это не то, есть покороче вариант и без доп модулей?

Comment: если берёте код [из другого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19797600/4279) на Stack Overflow, то приведите ссылку и автора укажите, [Есть ли формальные требования как следует упомянуть в своём ответе, что код взят из ответа на английском Stack Overflow и был модифицирован?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4897/23044)

Comment: @babyborn: вы можете удалить ваши комментарии, если больше неприменимы к текущей версии ответа. Хотя автору ответа следовало бы явно указать, что ответ был изменён после ваших комментариев (так я прочёл и подумал, что *"по обоим методам открывает в том же окне консоли"* относится к текущему коду, который должен и так работать ([его уже тестировали](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19797600/4279))